# Inserting the same fields from multiple tables (in a more efficient way)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm looking to avoid rewriting the same queries below (for each unique table):

```
Insert Into dbo.DatabaseNEW (Field1 , Field 2)
Select Field 1, Field 2  FROM OldDatabase.dbo.[Table 1] WHERE DESCRIPTION LIKE 'Something';

Insert Into dbo.DatabaseNEW (Field1 , Field 2)
Select Field 1, Field 2  FROM OldDatabase.dbo.[Table 2] WHERE DESCRIPTION LIKE 'Something';
```

I've tried combining the queries as below, but it doesn't work:

```
Insert Into dbo.DatabaseNEW (Field1 , Field 2)
Select Field 1, Field 2  FROM OldDatabase.dbo.[Table 1], OldDatabase.dbo.[Table 2] WHERE DESCRIPTION LIKE 'Something';
```

Any help?  Sorry for the noob question.  Thanks!

Comment: Does all tables look exactly the same?

Comment: Yes, @KayNelson all tables look EXACTLY the same.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the UNION ALL operator

```
Insert Into dbo.DatabaseNEW (Field1 , Field2)
(
Select Field1, Field2  FROM OldDatabase.dbo.[Table 1] WHERE DESCRIPTION LIKE 'Something'
UNION ALL
Select Field1, Field2  FROM OldDatabase.dbo.[Table 2] WHERE DESCRIPTION LIKE 'Something'
);
```